# NumerICs vs numerALs, what is the difference if any?

Tags: usage, mathematics, suffixes

I looked up MW but failed to see whether they are interchangeable.

On a daily basis I find difficulties in adjective forming, so I guess this is just one more of the -IC versus -AL dilemmas, no?

Comment: For most purposes you should recognise "numeric" as an *adjective* (i.e. - *"The digit 3 is a **numeric character**"*). Whereas "numeral" is a *noun* in itself (i.e. - *"The digit 3 is a **numeral**"*).

Comment: Thanks, so it is boiled  down to usage habits, because MW defines them both both as adjectives and nouns. To add to the confusion MW defines **numerICAL** as well but this time as adjective only.

Comment: Some estimated usage figures from Google Books: [a numeral expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+numeral+expression%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):1300, [a numeric expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+numeric+expression%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):23000, [a numerical expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+numerical+expression%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):126000.

Comment: Very good, didn't look until now, it appears you are quite right numberwise/ratiowise, with 1:10:100 ratio it is no wonder why noun takes over. Also, "numerals" yielded 2,490,000 while "numerics" 76,100.

Comment: Yes - checking prevalence (using Google Books or Internet search) for **word+s** can be a good way of checking how often **word** is used as a *noun*. But you need to watch out for cases where **word** might also be used as a *verb*, so it's generally better to search for some unambiguous text string in Google Books. (Besides which, they're *written* instances, so there won't be too many erroneous texts written by incompetent/non-native speakers.)

Answer (score 3):

*Numeral* (noun) is the shape that draw on the paper to represent a number.

*Numeric* (adj) lets us know that some noun represents some number.

In use:

> *0* and *O* look almost identical in many fonts.  But they are not the same.  The letter form *O* has an orthographic (spelling) value, but no **numeric** value, although it can be used to spell many great words like *book* and *hog.*
>
> Contrast that with the **numeral** *0*.  You can't spell anything with it, but it does have a **numeric** value, approximately halfway between -1 and 1.
>
> In some fonts, you can tell the two apart:  `0 is the numeral, O is the letter form with no numeric value.`
>
> In Rome, on the other hand, the letter form V also served as a **numeral,** so you could either use it to spell things, or to represent **numeric** values.

...and one more take on this, from the comments:

- *Forty-seven* is a number, expressed without the use of **numerals.** *47* is the same number, expressed using **numerals.**
- *Boobs* is a word referring to mammalian anatomy. `80085` is the punchline to a adolescent calculator joke that uses **numerals** to suggest the word "boobs."  The **numeric** value of 80085 is not important to the joke.

Comment: Thanks, very good. Can we replace 'numeric values' with just 'numericS', I wonder why the noun usage is kinda avoided, here one example: *Restricting our attention to such programming languages in general, it is observed that the lack of computational efficiency has proved to be the most important argument against object-oriented **numerics**. This aspect has indeed prevented serious use of OOP for **numerical work** until advent of C++.* /Numerical Methods and Software Tools in Industrial Mathematics/

Comment: I _think_ I have seen **numeric** used as a noun meaning "something which has the same value as some number" in programming.  (e.g.  _I declare my string variables in upper case. Then when I see ONE, I instantly know it is not a numeric._)  I am not a programmer, though, so I can't speak broadly about how the words are used in that field.  As a physical scientist/engineer in the U.S., I see **numeric** used as an adjective, interchangeably with **numerical.** We  use **numeral** _only_ to refer to the character.

Comment: Maybe the noun use of **numeric** is less common because in most contexts, people don't need a word for "something which represents a number, but isn't necessarily one." ?

Comment: Good to know. *In earlier versions of the standard (e.g., SQL-89), the data types were limited to exact **numerics**, approximate **numerics**, and character strings. In SQL-92, these have been augmented with bit strings, datetimes, and intervals. Each of these have ...* /Understanding the New SQL: A Complete Guide/

Comment: @Georgi You probably have noticed this, but **numerics** in the examples you are giving is not the plural of the noun form of **numeric** that I was describing in my previous comment. *Numerics** means something more like "arithmetic, statistics, and other number-related calculations."  We _do_ use this term (**numerics**) in engineering.  _(Q:  How should we split up the work?  A:  I'll do the writeup, if you can handle the numerics.)_  Similar to _running the numbers._

Comment: Right, I felt that it is a far-ffetched but I gave it anyway. Also I struggle with whether NUMERAL is the right term to designate sets as well as numbers, for instance, are 'quadruple' and 'hexadecad' numerals, I mean what is the right term for digits/numbers written in letters, I can't say it well, hope you get me.

Comment: "quadruple" is not a numeral in normal U.S. usage.  It is a word.  In _"x4"_, _x_ is a letter and _4_ is a numeral.  _Forty-seven_ is a number, expressed without the use of numerals.  _47_ is the same number, expressed using numerals.  _Boobs_ is a word referring to mammalian anatomy.  `80085` is the punchline to a adolescent calculator joke that uses numerals to suggest the word _"boobs"_.

Comment: Ay-ay, why I was under the impression that numeral is a letter-written ... numeral! In my dummy convention forty-seven was a numeral while the 47 was the number. I have much to ... unlearn.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric is often used in something like this: "0 has no numeric value", but you would use Numeral in a sentence like this "II is two in roman numerals".

Numeric - Indicating a number or value.

Numeral - A word number or symbol expressing a number

Comment: Thanks, my current understanding is that (as you said) numeral is the wordY representation, but I still can't see what is the role of 'numeric' then, can we say "Zero is (a) numeral/numeric"?

Comment: You would say something like " X has an numerical value of 1" Its another way of saying number.