# how to use multiple single words with a and an

Tags: sentence-construction, articles

I am trying to build a sentence that has many *single* words like this:

> It is not a product, a service, a desktop application, a machine, or an application but it is an architecture.

is that way or using *a* correct? or I should use just one *a* and one *an* like this:

> It is not a product, service, desktop application, machine, or an application..

#### Note:

I know that the sentence could be rewritten using *neither* and *nor*, but that is not my question. My question is about using many *a/an* or just one of them is enough.

Comment: FYI - Marco.  On ELL, the code markup (the tick) is frowned upon.  I tried to use it a few times when I started out, but was disabused of that idea quickly.  I now reserve it for instances when monospaced fonts are absolutely necessary. (e.g. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/numerics-vs-numerals-what-is-the-difference-if-any/48176#48176 )  I didn't edit your question, because I don't care much, but many people seem to.

Comment: @Adam please edit my question, i don't know these roles

Comment: Someone else already took care of it  :-)

Comment: Everything about your sentence is emphatic. The repetition of lots of nouns, the use of but, the delay in revealing what it is, and the repetition of *it is* an the final clause. For this reason, it would be much better to repeat the use of *a/n* in your example. If adds style and emphasis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really only need a single article, and that article matches the first item in your list:

> It is not a product, service, desktop application, machine, or application...

While it is true that you wouldn't say "a application" (since it starts with a vowel), by having declared the first item in the list as indefinite, the presumption of indefiniteness (a vs. the) is implied on all subsequent items in the list.

If your list were ordered differently, you'd write:

> It is not an application, product, service, desktop application, or machine ...

In either case, the repetition of the article on each item is superfluous, and may safely be omitted

---

Note, if you mix classes of nouns - definite, indefinite, and mass quantities, you need to mark at least one of each class. For example:

> Feel free to use a phone, fax, or the Internet to reach me.

It would be any old phone or fax, but since there is only one Internet, it needs the definite article.

---

N.B. Your sentence would read best if you say "It is not a product, service, desktop application, machine, or application, but rather an architecture." (or better yet, framework!)  But saying "rather" you signal the reader to the fact that you are switching to what the thing is.

Comment: The "extra" articles could be add emphasis though. Also, you might want to incorporate your comment into the answer - the OP doesn't get any notice that something has been updated unless you tag him with the '@' in the comment.

Comment: you removed the `an` from application? why please? application needs an not a, right?

Comment: Correctly - as I stated in the post, once you have identified the list members as being indefinite, you don't need to mark any more of them at all.

Comment: @AffableGeek Oh now i got u, so it doesn't matter if it is a or an when u have many single words. I just need to put a or an according to the first single word, then just using single words without any a or an

Comment: Exactly! Just make sure you mark the first noun correctly - a product or an application.

Comment: what if the first single word is not countable? like water or money?

Comment: then no mark is needed.  It is neither solid, liquid, nor gas.  Or It is not money, fame, or power.

Comment: @AffableGeek Although if you are mixing countable and uncountable, you would use an article, in front of the first countable?  _What motivates me? It is not money, fame, power, or a fancy car._  Contrast with: _It is not money, fame, power, or fancy cars._

Comment: That's such an odd construction :)  I'm trying to find an example of mixing both countable and uncountable nouns. I'd probably say what you've written there - but in speaking it, there would be an emphasis on "or even a car!"  Absent that emphasis, however, I suspect that you could get away without the article

Comment: @AffableGeek _For breakfast I usually have milk, bacon and a piece of toast.  My favorite meal thing to eat is not cereal, pork rinds, or a quesadilla._  Alright...I guess that is a bit of a stretch.  (I really wanted to make some kind of point with _He wears tan shoes with pink shoelaces, a polka dot vest, and man o man, tan shoes with pink shoelaces, and a big Panama with a purple hat band_  ....But I can't figure out how.)

Comment: So what you've established, and I think this is right, is that an indefinite article and an uncountable mass are different classes. Come to think of it, you'd say: "you can use a phone, fax, device, or the Internet." If you were mixing definite and indefinite items in a list.

Comment: @AffableGeek Yeah - I think that's right.  And your list illustrates it much better than mine did.  (In the corner of the U.S. I occupy, we'd say "mobile device,")

Comment: If I weren't on my mobile device, I would have said that too :)

Comment: The best way to think about it, in my opinion, is that a/an is semantically *one* word that is pronounced differently depending on the sound that follows it, and written according to how it's pronounced. It has no problem distributing over a list, and the a/an choice is still made based on the following sound.

Comment: This also helps explain why you have "an elephant" but "a big elephant": a/an isn't agreeing *grammatically* with "elephant", it's modifying its sound to concord with "e" or "b".

Answer (score 4):

I believe that your question was more around whether or not to repeat the "a/an" in the list of words.

You can be grammatically correct in either usage, but when an item in your list is potentially countable (can be a unspecific or specific amount), then your meaning can become different.

For example, take this sentence:

> I had an egg, watermelon, and milk for breakfast.

It makes sense here to not specify the article in front of "milk" and "watermelon" because I had an indeterminate amount. However, it would be very strange to say I had ***a*** watermelon, because I did not eat an entire watermelon. It would also be very strange to say I had ***a*** milk, because milk is not a single item.

However, if we take this example sentence:

> I had an egg, an apple, and an orange for breakfast.

This makes sense to enumerate my amount of egg and apple. I had a single one of each, not some indeterminate amount. If I leave out the article, the meaning of my sentence changes to say that I had just *some* amount of egg or *some* amount of apple.

Comment: If the first one in the list can only be a count noun, you cannot "leave out" the article: *'I had apple, bacon, and orange juice for breakfast.'

Comment: Would it be acceptable/necessary to say **a** watermelon, if I *did* eat an entire watermelon?

Comment: It would definitely be acceptable if you did indeed eat an entire watermelon, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Either way. It is a matter of style.

But, first, it is hard to guess what you mean by using *architecture* as a count noun.

Second, in the second sentence, you do not need *an* before *application*; the one *a* at the beginning applies to all the words, including *application*.

Comment: _Architecture_ is a computer science/informatics term which is a countable noun.  It is odd to the layman's ear, but his usage is correct in that context.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no you dont need to use that many a / an s. one is perfectly fine used like this:

```
It is not a product, service, desktop application, machine, or an application..
```

Hope this answers your question (sorry for the previous confusion).

Comment: Sorry what are you talking about? I do know when to use `a` and when to use `an`. That is not my question buddy

Comment: then what is your quetion

Comment: wait i get it im fixing my answer now

Comment: my question is about repeat the `a/an` or using one `a` and one `an` is enough

Comment: I fixed the answer

Comment: it is not me who downvote

Comment: could you select this as your answer if I answered your question properly please?

Comment: +1 for your answer, I am checking all the other answers, and wait for some understanding